# how can I use gtk responses

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I have a gtk dialog with an OK button
I want a specific function to be executed when the OK button is pressed so I used the following code:

```
    static struct data callback_params;
    callback_params.entry = gtk_entry_new();
    callback_params.file = config;
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), callback_params.entry);
    g_signal_connect(dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_set),&callback_params);
    g_signal_connect_swapped (dialog, "response",G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy),dialog);
    gtk_window_set_modal (GTK_WINDOW(dialog), TRUE);
    gtk_widget_show_all (dialog);


void add_new_set(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer callback_params)
{
  g_print ("%s\n",gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
  fputs("set \"",((FILE *)((struct data *) callback_params)->file));
  fputs(gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry),((FILE *)((struct data *) callback_params)->file));
  fputs("\"",((FILE *)((struct data *) callback_params)->file));
}
```

which is working fine, ecept the close(x) button executes that function as well, I understand this is the normal behaviour for the "response" signal, I want the (x) to close the dialog box and not run the function

I believe this should have something to do with gtk responses such as the:
GTK_RESPONSE_OK
GTK_RESPONSE_CLOSE

but I'm not sure how I would use those in my code.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the signature of your response handler: that `response_id` looks promising, right? Compare that to GTK_RESPONSE_OK (or other values) to find out what the user decided.

Comment: I don't know what the response handler is

Comment: It's the signal handler function connected to the 'response'  signal, in your case `add_new_set()`.